# how to set list item of google document using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm creating google doc document using app script, most of the text is nested list item. the Glyphtype is set to be NUMBER.
Does anybody know if it's possible to change the list item type to be as shown in the picture?

[image: current and desired result]

Comment: If you got this working, could you please share the solution?

Comment: Please star the issue so they can work on it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765756